# Understanding MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, homework, circuits

[image]

I don't understand how I can find RS, RD and RG so that ID=0.1mA. Help.

Comment: This looks like homework, check the notes you have and show what you have done so far - this is not a homework completion service.

Comment: Indeed you have to show what you have tried. For sure this must have been explained to you otherwise it is cruel to let you figure that out yourself. I'll give a hint: With the given \$V_t\$ and \$k_n\$ you can calculate what the \$V_{GS}\$ needs to be to make \$I_D\$ = 1 mA.

Comment: BTW, you misread the assignment: your design should choose values of Rs, Rd and Rg to accomplish actually **three** specifics and not just a Ids = 0.1 mA. Indeed, they need to allow you to have a certain input resistance and a certain voltage swing at the drain terminal as well.